# Given a DCEL where the twin is equal to the next of an edge, how many faces can the subdivision have?

Tags: computational-geometry, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to solve exercise 2.7 from the book "Computational Geometry - Algorithms and Applications" (by Berg et al.), which says

> Given a doubly-connected edge list representation of a subdivision where Twin(e) = Next(e) holds for every half-edge e, how many faces can the subdivision have at most?

I think that the solution is an edge that links only two vertices, and the twin may be the next. So, the only face could be the infinity face. They could be more pairs of vertices linked by an edge, but only if they are disjoint on each. Are there other possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you're correct.

Given that Next(e) equals Twin(e) for all half-edges e, then IncidentFace(Next(e)) equals IncidentFace(Twin(e)).  And since we know that IncidentFace(e) always equals IncidentFace(Next(e)) then we can conclude that IncidentFace(e) equals IncidentFace(Twin(e)) for all half-edges.  So no edge lies on the boundary of two different faces.  And if no edge bounds two different faces, then there cannot be more than one face.